# Populating a Dojox Grid

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

The problem I am having is getting my grid to fill when I run my select command. It sees the number of features and creates the correct number of cells in my grid but that is about it. It should populate the grid with the matching fields from the feature class. I am really new at JS and HTML, 1 month under my belt. Any ideas that get me closer to getting this to work would be great.

```
var map, selectionToolbar, wllFeatureLayer;//, grid, store;

function init() {
  map = new esri.Map("map", { 
    basemap: "topo",
    center: [-112, 34.537],
    zoom: 7
  });

  var sect = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("https://my.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/crcwc/crcwc/MapServer/5", {
    mode:  esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields:["*"]
  });   

  var tShips = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("https://my.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/crcwc/crcwc/MapServer/4", {
    mode:  esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields:["*"]
  });


  var fieldsSelectionSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setColor("red");

  //Popup window settings
  var content = "<b>API Number</b>: ${apino}"  +
                "<br><b>Permit Number Operator</b>: ${operator}" +
                "<br><b>Well Name County</b>: ${county}" +
                "<br><b>Township-Range, Section </b>: T${twp}-R${rge}, Sec. ${section_}" +
                "<br><b>Depth</b>: ${drillertotaldepth} ft" +
                "<br><b>Formation</b>: ${formationtd}" +
                "<br><b>Download Scanned TIFF</b>: TIFF" +
                "<br><b>Download LAS Data</b>: LAS";                    
  var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("Well Info", content);
  wellFeatureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://services.azgs.az.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/aasggeothermal/AZWellHeaders/MapServer/0",{
    mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND, //data on demand
    infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
    outFields: ["*"]
  });
//Controls what the select and clear buttons do
  wellFeatureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("welltype='O&Gexplor'");
  wellFeatureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(fieldsSelectionSymbol);

  map.addLayers([wellFeatureLayer, sect, tShips]);

  dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", initSelectToolbar);
}

//Listens for selection box and initializes the buttons
function initSelectToolbar(map) {
  selectionToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map); //creates toolbar
  var selectQuery = new esri.tasks.Query();


  //Selects data once box is drawn
  dojo.connect(selectionToolbar, "onDrawEnd", function(geometry) {
    selectionToolbar.deactivate();
    selectQuery.geometry = geometry;

    wellFeatureLayer.selectFeatures(selectQuery, esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (featureSet) {
        updateGrid(featureSet);
    //window.alert("Me!");
    });

    });


}

/*function updateGrid(featureSet){
    //window.alert("Pick me.");
    var data = {//[];
    //dojo.forEach(featureSet, function (entry, i) {
        //data.push({
          id:feature.attributes.objectid,
          apino:feature.attributes.apino,
          depth:feature.attributes.drillertotaldepth,
          wellname:feature.attributes.wellname

         });
        );
    grid.setStore(data);
    grid.refresh();
    //grid.setQuery({ OBJECTID: '*' });
    };
    */                                                  

function updateGrid(featureSet){
    //window.alert("Pick me.");
    var dataForGrid = [];
    dojo.forEach(featureSet, function (feature) {
        dataForGrid.push([feature.objectid,feature.apino,feature.drillertotaldepth,feature.wellname])
          //id:entry.attributes.objectid,
         // apino:entry.attributes.apino,
         // depth:entry.attributes.drillertotaldepth,
         // wellname:entry.attributes.wellname

        // });
        });
    var data = {
        items:dataForGrid
        };
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:data});
    grid.setStore(store);
    //grid.refresh();
    //grid.setQuery({ OBJECTID: '*' });
    };




dojo.ready(init);


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where/how is your grid defined? Is there an error loading the grid, or do the cells display "..."?

The online samples also have several examples that use a grid:

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/fl_dgrid.html
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/find_map_datagrid.html